# Stryker can't find WorkerExtensions.AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, .net, stryker-net

I'm trying to run Stryker in my .NET 8.0 solution but it is looking for a file in the net6.0 release folder. This file doesn't appear to be available in the net8.0 folder either

> An error occurred during the mutation test run
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
> path 'C:...\obj\Release\net6.0\WorkerExtensions.AssemblyInfo.cs'

How can I get Stryker to run mutation tests on my solution?

Comment: have you taken a look at this? https://github.com/stryker-mutator/stryker-net/issues/1859

Comment: @akg179 Yes. I tried removing the reference to the solution file but it didn't help

Comment: Is there any non-ascii character in your path? (as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32219279/6309))

Comment: What version of stryker are you running?